# How to make a shape in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, uibezierpath

How to make a shape like this

[image]

```
func createShape() {
        bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: .zero)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width , y: self.frame.origin.y))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2 , y: self.frame.height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2  + 33 , y: self.frame.height))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height / 2), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width/2 - 33, y:self.frame.height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height / 2))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: .zero)
        bezierPath.close()
    }
```

and as a result i got

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: You are almost there. You just need 1 curve. Make the control points park at the edge of the view. Zero x and width x.

Comment: can you please share the code if  it is possible  @Desdenova

Comment: I don't agree with this close vote. He knows what he wants, he tried his code and almost got it right, and he came to the perfect place to get it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read how a curve work [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/core-graphics-part-4-a-path-a-path/)

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: .zero)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: self.frame.height/2))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to:  CGPoint(x:self.frame.width , y: self.frame.height / 2), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (self.frame.height+self.frame.width)/2), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: (self.frame.height+self.frame.width)/2))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: .zero)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems I was wrong with my comment on the question. If we use two curves we could get a perfect half circle. Nevertheless this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the drawing that you need.. it will give you perfect circle with `UIBezierpath` `addArc` method

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

 private lazy var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.borderWidth = 5
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        
        
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        shapeLayer.path = drawShape()
    }
    
    
    private func drawShape() -> CGPath {
        
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        bezierPath.move(to: .zero)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.midY/2))
        bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y:  bounds.midY), radius: bounds.midX, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
        
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: 0))
        bezierPath.close()
        
        return bezierPath.cgPath
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

with Background color

[image]